# Incorrect message coming when sending 403 status code after hosting on IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-403, action-filter, asp.net-authorization

I have created a custom authorization filter in my .net MVC application for role-based authorization. I am sending 403 status code and custom error message when the user is not authorized in handleunauthorizedRequest method (please see the code below)

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!this.Roles.Split(',').Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole))
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode =(int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("Not Authorized");
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
            //filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Not Authorized");

        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }


    }
```

I am getting the correct error message ("Not Authorized") when running the application on the localhost. However, after making the application live in the IIS server, I was getting the default error page for 403 status code so I removed the default error page for 403 status from IIS. Now I am getting the below error message :

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Can anyone please tell me where is this message coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this after reading a few blogs and Microsoft docs. I have added the below line in my web.config file to keep the response untouched

```
 <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

You can read about httpErros here: [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/ms690497(v=vs.90))